# Use SOCKS proxy for several IP addresses on OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, network, proxy

I just wanna use socks proxy for some ip addresses. I found this setting:

[image]

Sorry for non-English screenshot. Here is OSX Networking settings for SOCKS proxy. I can see only "black list" for ip addresses to access without proxy. But I need "white list" of ip addresses.

Comment: What do you want to do? Use an IP as a SOCKS proxy server?

Comment: @LaX I wanna use SOCKS proxy just for several IP addresses which are blocked by my ISP.

Comment: That's different then: if your ISP blocks these proxy, you cannot white-list them yourself. They are the only one who can unblock them. A solution might be to use a non-blocked proxy/vpn to then connect to these blocked SOCKS

Comment: @LaX for example ISP blocked github.com :) I wanna use SOCKS proxy to access github.com only. All other connections should avoid this proxy

Comment: Oh ok. That wasn't what I understood, sorry. Now it all makes sense, but I don't know the answer to your question. I hope it helped others understand it better though.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed your screen shot. I just learned how to say прокси-сервер!

I believe what you'd be doing is asking the proxy redirector to make exceptions to its exceptions. I think this will probably not be possible.

There is a kind of tool which may work better for you.  It is called a URL re-writer or URL re-director.  Instead of setting up a SOCKS proxy, which would be designed to forward every kind of web call, a URL re-writer would watch all the outgoing connection requests and replace just the ones that match to wherever you re-direct them.  This is very good for sending a small number of addresses or domains to another place--like your proxy server or tunnel endpoint.

These URL rewriters come in two flavors: the sort installed in routers—-like squid—-or they can be browser plug-ins. Some routers have this feature built in and call it "transparent web redirecting."

There's a plug-in for Safari called "urlrewrite-safari" that lives at https://github.com/sjmulder/urlrewrite-safari .  There's one for Firefox called "Redirector" which works much the same. I haven't looked to see what's there for Google Chrome.

The only snag is that when you do a web search for "URL rewrite" or "URL redirect" you also end up with a lot of server-side redirection stuff, too.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need more system tool than browser extension. `github` is really banned in Russia :( so I need `git` to work too. Right now I am using froovpn.com.

Comment: Ah!  Well, you're already well ahead of the game if you're using from, I think.  The only things I've heard of that would do what you're describing would be [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com) or [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com). I've never tried either of them, and they're both commercial. I'm sorry I don't have a more open suggestion.